# how i can I draw a checkbox with item in each "tabbutton" using QML?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qml, qtquick2

I am making a simple Todo-list for learning QtQuick + Python.
see attached image.
my concept is:

1. put the task on textField box
2. push the "+" button, then adding the task to the list.
3. at the same time, adding the task with checkbox on each tab("All", "Active", "Done")
   4...
   5...
   I finished #2, and I don't know how I to do #3.

todo_main.py

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from todo_controller import TodoController
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

def main() -> int:
    app: QGuiApplication = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationDisplayName("Todo List")
    controller: TodoController = TodoController()
    

    engine: QQmlApplicationEngine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    
    # engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", model)
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("controller", controller)
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(str(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")))
    return app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

todo_controller.py.

```
from typing import Union

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot ,pyqtProperty


# from threading import Thread


class TodoController(QObject):
   
    def __init__(self, parent: Union[QObject, None] = None) -> None:
        """Init class."""
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.tasks = []
   
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def add_task(self, task: str) -> None:
        if task == "":
            return "Task cannot be empty!"
        else:
            self.tasks.append(task)
    
    @pyqtSlot()
    def print_task(self) -> None:
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14
import QtQml.Models 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls.Material  2.14
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.14


ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 480
    height: 320

    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        columns: 3
        columnSpacing : 10
        rows: 10
        rowSpacing: 50

        Text { text: "   Todo-List:"; font.pixelSize: 24; font.bold: true; color: "red"}
        TextField{
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.row: 0
            id: textinput
            font.pixelSize: 13
            font.bold: true
            placeholderText: qsTr("Whats needs to be done?")
            onTextChanged:console.log("text is changed: " + text)
        }
        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "+"
            font.pixelSize: 15
            font.bold: true
            // onClicked: console.log("text is clicked: " + textinput.text)
            onClicked: controller.add_task(textinput.text), console.log("text input:",controller.print_task())
        }
        TabBar {
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.row: 4
            TabButton {
                id:all
                text: qsTr("All")
                width:implicitWidth
               
            }
            TabButton {
                id:active
                text: qsTr("Active")
                width:implicitWidth
            }
            TabButton {
                id:done
                text: qsTr("Done")
                width:implicitWidth
            }
        }
        
     
    }
    
    
    
 
}
```

code also attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Fb2.png)

1. put the task on textField box
2. push the "+" button, then adding the task to the list.
3. at the same time, adding the task with checkbox on each tab("All", "Active", "Done") 4... 5... I finished #2, and I don't know how I to do #3.